# Finding the basis of the sum of two spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I'm given two spaces $L_1 = \{ x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}^*$ and $L_2= \{ y_1,y_2,...,y_l\}^*$ . 
How do i prove that the basis of $\ L_1+L_2 $ can be any base of this system $\{ x_1,x_2,...,x_k,y_1,y_2,.....,y_l\} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L_1$ is $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$ and $L_2$ is $\{y_1, y_2, .. y_n\}$ then of course the basis of $L_1 + L_2$ is a basis for the system $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n, y_1, y_2, ... , y_n\}$. Suppose that we have $\alpha$ is a basis of $L_1 + L_2$. Consider a vector $x$ that is in $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n, y_1, y_2, ... , y_n\}$ but not in $\alpha$. But by definition $L_1 + L_2$ is:
$$\{x = v + w \ |\ v \in L_1, w \in L_2\}$$
So $x = a_1x_1 + ... a_nx_n + b_1y_1 + ... b_ny_n$ and $a_1x_1 + ... a_nx_n \in L_1$ and $b_1y_1 + ... b_ny_n \in L_2$. Look at the definition of $\alpha$, then this is a direct contradiction.